How to get logs from service container in Github Actions
I have a Github Actions workflow which runs on a container.
Besides that i also have a service-container based on docker:dind running as a docker-service.
Both of them are setup as siblings bei Github Actions.
The docker-service opens up a tcp connection which the workflow container connects to. This works.
At some point the workflow container is running maven tests which require access to the docker-service to run a testcontainers container.
Unfortunately the setup of the testcontainers fails with the error message:

2024-09-06T09:04:13.268  INFO --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Unable to determine fallback DNS. Please check if 'localstack.cloud' is reachable by your configured DNS serversDNS fallback will be disabled.
2024-09-06T09:04:13.269  WARN --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Error starting the DNS server: No upstream dns server found.

I cant make any sense of that error, so i try to find a way to get (docker-demon) logs from the docker-service container. But i didnt find a way to establish that connections and get any logs.
If i run these containers on my local machine side by side everything works fine...
Any ideas about that?

See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26282.

Are you using a self-hosted runner for  this job?
